# How to Remove the numbers after the dot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a drop function to get the value and show in an input field but I just need it as a decimal number

```
events: {
  drop: function() {
    document.getElementById('point-temp').value = this.y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you tried so far.... and which tutorial/code didn't work for you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you round the number.

```
 events: {
    drop: function() {
      document.getElementById('point-temp').value = (Math.round(this.y));
    }
  }
```

Comment: actually all of the answers i got are correct but your one is the best one coz if the number for ex. 66.5 it give it to me as 67 and when its less than 66.5 it give it as 66.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can split that value using dot and consider the first value in array:

```
     events: {
        drop: function() {
          document.getElementById('point-temp').value = (this.y).toString().split('.')[0];
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) is what you need.

```
events: {
  drop: function() {
    document.getElementById('point-temp').value = Math.trunc(this.y);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<input placeholder="new Temperature" id="point-temp" type="text" class="field"  value="">
```

```js
console.log(Math.trunc(3.2))
console.log(Math.trunc(4.6))
console.log(Math.trunc(7))
```